# Acceleration Absolute from all Non-Accelerating Frame of references

Tags: acceleration, absolute-units

Is Acceleration Absolute from all Non-Accelerating Frame of references?
Though experiment:
Imagine cars on a two-way highway travelling at different velocities. A motorbike is accelerating at A'.
From all cars, the acceleration would be observed as A'.
Does this mean,
Is Acceleration Absolute from all Non-Accelerating Frame of references?

Comment: I believe the same answer applies here as in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173/is-acceleration-an-absolute-quantity